# Strange w3c validation on a certain points

Tags: xhtml, w3c

Can someone help me and explain me why this isn't validated?

**My doctype:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**The errors:**

```
 1. line 55 column 14 - error: document
    type does not allow element "div"
    here; missing one of "object",
    "applet", "map", "iframe", "button",
    "ins", "del" start-tag

    <div id="tabs">

 2. line 62 column 24 - Fout: document
    type does not allow element "div"
    here; missing one of "object",
    "applet", "map", "iframe", "button",
    "ins", "del" start-tag

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

  3. line 65 column 22 - Fout: document
     type does not allow element "div"
     here; missing one of "object",
     "applet", "map", "iframe", "button",
     "ins", "del" start-tag



  4. <div id="calculator">

     line 76 column 19 - Fout: document
     type does not allow element "div"
     here; missing one of "object",
     "applet", "map", "iframe", "button",
     "ins", "del" start-tag

     <div id="feature">

  5. line 83 column 7 - Fout: end tag for
     "a" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
     specified 

     </div>
```

This is the html, which can be viewed here also.

http://www.coldcharlie.nl/test/

Comment: not without seeing the actual html ...

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because you have `<div>` s where they're not permitted by the doctype.

Comment: I placed the html in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put a block level element such as `<div>` inside an inline element such as `<span>` or `<a>`

On line 55 you have an `<a>` element *(hyperlink)* that isn't closed. Then you have few `<div>`s. The validator thinks these divs are inside the `<a>`.

Comment: Great, I needed to close the <a href, after closing it, every other error was gone too. Thanks!